# My iPhone 6 has a problem charging

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6 has a problem charging it will charge then not charge then it will repeat it. When it gets to 100% and it get taken off the charger then a few minutes it will die.

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: You may have a defective battery. Is there an Apple store nearby you can take your phone into? They’ll be able to run some tests and figure out what’s wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect your battery to a Mac, get the app CoconutBattery and run it with your iphone connected to the Mac. It will tell you if iPhone battery is charging properly. I used it with my iPhone 6 and it correctly identified that battery was faulty and not charging properly. I took my phone in for a new battery.

Answer (score 0):

You have an iPhone 6, which means you can be updated to the latest iOS version. The latest has a battery health indicator in your battery settings. Can you check that at all?

At least update your question with details of your iPhone. iOS version, are you using an apple certified charger? Have you tried resetting your iPhone through a computer and reinstalling the latest iOS?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the battery or the battery port.